# getting JSON data from server with Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-rails

I have a Court.rb model (inheriting from Active Record) in my Rails app that I'm also using with ember-rails gem.

I created a Court model for it in Ember

```
 App.Court = DS.Model.extend({
    jurisdictionId: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
  });
```

There is a courts resource in the router

```
  App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("courts");
    this.resource("about");

  });
```

and, to retrieve the data, I created a courts route that calls findAll() on the Court model

```
App.CourtsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Court.findAll();
  }

});
```

Ember's giving me a long error message for this, the final part of which says  `has no method 'findAll'` . I also tried to use `App.Court.find()` and got the same error.

This is essentially what Ryan Bates did to retrieve data from the server in his Railscast on Ember
He created an Entry model

```
Raffler.Entry = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  winner: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

And also an Entries route that calls find on the model

```
 Raffler.EntriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model:  -> Raffler.Entry.find()
```

Can you explain what I might be doing wrong to get this to work?

Comment: Which version of Ember/Ember Data are you using?

Comment: @kroofy I ran this command yesterday to get the latest version `rails generate ember:install --head` whatever that is.

Comment: Try using `return this.store.find('court');` in the model hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running the latest version of Ember Data,

Try using:

`return this.store.find('court');` instead of `return App.Court.findAll();`

Here's a jsfiddle showing a simple structure: http://jsfiddle.net/XUmTC/2/

For more information of the transition look here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Thanks for trying but it gave me an error. `Assertion failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not {courts: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...` I thought Ember needed the root `courts` (in this case) in the json returned from server. Is that the problem do you think?

Comment: It should use the root key `courts`, maybe the JSON is not formatted correctly? Can you make a JSfiddle with fixture data?

Comment: I tried to adapt someone else's Ember fiddle with some fixture data but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. However, you can see the fixture data here along with the code I added. http://jsfiddle.net/backyardguy/PkT8x/365/

Comment: Added a fiddle to it. So if that's not working for you when you switch to real backend, it could be that the data is not properly formatted.

Comment: thanks a lot. I thought the data that Ember expects JSON data to have the root (in this case 'courts'), but you removed it.